# Do Karaites Celebrate Purim?

Tags: purim, megillat-esther, non-rabbinic-judaism

[Karaite Judaism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karaite_Judaism) recognizes the Tanakh only as its source of Jewish Law and practice. The Tanakh includes the Book of Esther. A simple reading of [Esther 9](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3309.htm):20-32 has at least some segment of Jews accepting the days of Purim upon themselves and later generations. verse 31 mentions fasting and crying as well, [The Fast of Esther](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_of_Esther) in Rabbinic Judaism.

Do Karaite Jews celebrate Purim and The Fast of Esther? If not, how do they interpret those verses in Esther 9?

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1531/759

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They do. You can see in the [Karaite Jews of America website](http://www.karaites.org/purim.html) that they celebrate Purim on a similar date (though in Adar I in leap years).

Comment: A proclaimed Karaite who attends my shul confirmed this. He stated that they do not celebrate Chanukah. Though, I have seen him eating *latkes* and *sufganiyot*, though he claims that the only reason he does that is b/c they taste good.

Comment: @DanF hahahah maybe some do and some don't.